# Internal drive on pc formatted for hfs

Tags: post-production

If I want to transfer files from an external mac hfs formatted drive to my PC.
And I have an extra internal drive formatted on my pc for hfs do I still need something like mac drive?

Comment: This is not related to Sound Design and will be closed.  You may have better luck on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) where this kind of question is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

...and your PC can read that Mac formatted drive?

Sounds like your computer already has a version of Mac Drive installed. Do you have an older version of Pro Tools that installed HFS+ support? If so, that's an older version of Mac Drive, and you should be fine.

Just a heads up, Avid is no longer paying for the right to distribute HFS+ support with Pro Tools. If you upgrade to 10, it gets uninstalled. You'll need to purchase Mac Drive at that point, or else your PC will no longer be able to read Mac formatted drives. I've heard that some people have been able to preserve the HFS+ support by uninstalling the old version of Pro Tools (preserving HFS+ support), then installing 10. I've never spoken to anyone who has done this though, and it might be conjecture on the part of the people who have mentioned it.